# Javascript addEventListener function call

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me how can I make the function `strikeText` work? I get this error in browser inspect.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: newButton is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.strikeText (todo.js:29)

**PS:** The inline function works but if I want to make a separate function it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="myForm">
      <input type="text" id="inputId" value="">
      <button type="button" id="submitButton">Add</button>
      <ul id="list">
         <li>
            <button type="button">Do that</button>
         </li>
         <li>
            <button type="button">Do this</button>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </form>
   <script src="todo.js">
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var submitB = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var striked = false;
submitB.addEventListener("click", addLi);

function addLi() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    var ulList = document.getElementById("list");
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    var newText = document.createTextNode(input);
    newButton.appendChild(newText);
    newButton.addEventListener("click", strikeText);
    newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    newLi.appendChild(newButton);
    ulList.appendChild(newLi);
    var reset = document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function strikeText() {
    striked = !striked;
    switch (striked) {
        case true:
            newButton.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            break;
        case false:
            newButton.style.textDecoration = "none";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `newButton` is not defined within the scope of your function.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Yeah i figured it out,but how can i pass it to the function?

Comment: Generally, you either put it in the global scope or pass it around as a param.

Comment: Ok I will try to find a solution,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jmargolisvt said, the newButton is an unknown variable in your strikeText function. Solution: use 'this' instead:

```
case true:
this.style.textDecoration="line-through";
break;
case false:
this.style.textDecoration="none";
break;
```

Also, what worked in my case was using the strikeText parameter:

```
function strikeText(event){
  striked=!striked;
  switch(striked){
    case true:
    event.target.style.textDecoration="line-through";
    break;
    case false:
    event.target.style.textDecoration="none";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: My first version also worked in IE11. Can you verify that you changed both lines? Maybe, you could paste your code in the comment or something?

Comment: You can try printing the value of "this" variable using console.log(this) to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Its working here with the snippet as below.. so only possible reason will be where you javascript code is make sure its executed after load and accessed after DOM is ready

```js
var submitB = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var striked=false;

submitB.addEventListener("click", addLi);

function addLi() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  var ulList = document.getElementById("list");
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  var newText = document.createTextNode(input);


  newButton.appendChild(newText);
  newButton.addEventListener("click",strikeText);
  newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");


  newLi.appendChild(newButton);
  ulList.appendChild(newLi);
  var reset = document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function strikeText(){

  striked=!striked;
  switch(striked){
    case true:
    newButton.style.textDecoration="line-through";
    break;
    case false:
    newButton.style.textDecoration="none";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>


<head>

    <title>To Do List</title>

</head>


<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="text" id="inputId" value="">
        <button type="button" id="submitButton">Add</button>
        <ul id="list">
            <li><button type="button">Do that</button></li>
            <li><button type="button">Do this</button></li>
        </ul>
    </form>

    <script src="todo.js">

    </script>

</body>


</html>
```